# Issue related to Powershell send-mail

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell send-mail command to send mail. It is working fine. But I cant see the mail which I sent in ***"sent items"***. I  can see it if I sent mail manually, but I am not able to understand why it is not visible if i sent a mail using send-mail command.

Thanks

Comment: because its not using a mail client such as outlook. You're simply sending an smtp message to the mail server and the mail server is delivering it.

Comment: ok, is there any option to see the mail in "sent items" by using send-mail command?

Comment: not to my knowledge no because technically you are not sending it from your mailbox, you are simply telling the email server who the sender is.

Comment: @tanijoshi - no, you can't do it with the built in PoSh cmdlet. you CAN do it with a COM object by using COM to call your email client - if your email client supports COM. do a search for `powersehll send mail with outlook` to see some examples of how to do that.

Comment: You will have to "roll your own" to do that, by invoking Outlook to do the actual work. This will involve loading a COM object and manipulating its properties and methods directly. I've done it, as SMTP is blocked from within my organization's network; it's not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function which creates an Outlook "Draft". I do it this way so that the e-mail can be reviewed before hitting "Send". This may not work for you; perhaps you'd want to add a send command at the end. But what you describe wanting to do is probably going to need outlook available on the system which is executing the commands.

It will check to see if you have a mail profile set up first, but otherwise it's not super-robust.

```
Function Compose-Email {
    Param ([String]$recipients, [string]$subject, [string]$body)
    $reg="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles"
    $child=(Get-ChildItem -Path $reg).name

    if (!((Get-ChildItem -Path $reg).name)) {
        Write-Error "No Mail Profile found! Cannot compose Draft."
    }
    else {
        $olFolderDrafts = 16
        $ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
        $ns = $ol.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

        # call the save method to save the email in the drafts folder
        $mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)

        $Mail.Recipients.Add($recipients)
        $Mail.Subject = $subject
        $Mail.Body = $body
        $Mail.save()
        $mail.display()
    }
}
```